# Can I add views to a scrollview without inflating/re-inflating layouts?

Tags: android, layout, view

I would like to take an existing `ScrollView` with a view in it, and add more views, dynamically (at runtime) to the `ScrollView` container.

Is it possible to add these views without having to create a new layout and inflate it? If so, what's the general process for adding these views dynamically?

For the sake of this question, assume the views are `TextView`...

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `ScrollView` can only have one child, so it doesn't make sense to add more children to it directly.  Lets say your `ScrollView` has a `LinearLayout` inside of it, then you can add more views to the `LinearLayout`:

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.my_linear_layout);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
layout.addView(textView);
```